# React - Realtime Data

Tags: reactjs, api

Fairly new to React so please forgive me.

I'm trying to build out a real time dashboard using data from an API.

Current thought is to use useEffect along with Fetch and an interval on the API to pull in the data and update the dashboard.  Is this the best approach? I've been reading about EventSource and think maybe that would be faster?

Comment: This is going to be opinion based so is not a good question.  The usage of react is completely unrelated to dealing with a backend supplying "realtime" data. Are you asking how to architect a system or are you asking how to use react with changing data?  The first question is better server by just trying something and then seeing if it works. For react question start by learning a bit about react and the answer will be very obvious.

Comment: I'm asking for opinions on what is the best way to update data in real time with React. I understand HOW to update the data on the page.   using Fetch seems a bit clunky and you have to wait.  EventSource seems to push data to the page and maybe faster.  As I'm new to development with React I'm wondering if others may have done this before and what their opinions may be.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to await a fetch. useState can have some empty values and your useEffect can fetch for the data and then you can set the state with your results

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is a react hook for functional components to replace/reduce the class component built-in methods: `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` into just one hook.

React is pushing to utilize this hook so in my opinion if you're making a react app, you should use useEffect to trigger your fetches.